# key char ovveride method throws illegalStateException on blackberry simulator

Tags: blackberry

When i use this method,  its throws illegal state expression on blackberry simulator.

```
protected boolean keyChar(char c, int status, int time) 
    {
        if (c == Keypad.KEY_ESCAPE) 
        {
                      UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen());
        }
                return super.keyChar(c, status, time);
```

}

if i give the return type true, No error display on  simulator.

when i use the super.keyChar(c,status,time). it throw illegal state expression.

But in device no error display. Only on blackberry simulator. wht is the problem on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
protected boolean keyChar(char c, int status, int time) 
{
    if (c == Keypad.KEY_ESCAPE) 
    {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen());
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
    return super.keyChar(c, status, time);
}
```

Comment: sorry still i got same erron on simulator

Answer (score 0):

```
protected boolean keyChar(char c, int status, int time) 
{
    if (c == Characters.ESCAPE) 
    {
       UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen());

    }
return true;
}
```

try this one. This will work.

And you can solve your problem by `returning true` from your if block and `return super.keyChar(c, status, time);` from else part. :)

Comment: if i give the return type true, i can't enter the text on textbox on active screen. Key char method not allow to enter the key on textbox.

Comment: i think you want to pop up screen without pushing it on the stack.